# Build step failed with exception org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, devops

I get below error when trying to deploy a WAR using Jenkins.

I created new Deploy-to-staging project, edited its config as follows:

- In Build, select copy artifacts from another project 
  [select the project artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vVTC.png)
- [Select Post-build Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZa0k.png)

On my attempt to build the (Project Build) code, Deploy-to-staging fails, and I get

> ERROR: Build step failed with exception
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Deploy-to-staging/webapp/target/webapp.war]
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:188)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
>       at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1844)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
>   Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The username and password you provided are not correct (error 401)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:698)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:876)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:889)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:173)
>       ... 17 more
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8090//manager/text/list
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:571)
>       ... 20 more
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The username and password you provided are not correct (error 401)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:698)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:876)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:889)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:173)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
>       at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1844)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8090//manager/text/list
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:571)
>       ... 20 more
>   Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

How can I fix this?

My tomcat credentials, located in [tomcat directory]/conf/tomcat-users.xml, are as follows:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-script,admin-gui" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Comment tag Valve in `context.xml` files

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
```

There are multiple `context.xml` files in tomcat directory, update following context.xml files and restart tomcat service-

- `/apache-tomcat-8.5.41/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml`
- `/apache-tomcat-8.5.41/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have error 401 for username and password. In the pic you send username is `sparsh` but in `context.xml` you use `tomcat` as a username.
Try to set correct username/password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).